# How to perform a model that represents an existing table or a database view?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to create a database view from django instead of associate a model from an existing database table. I'm new in django world and i don't know how how can i do this. Anyone have any ideia where to start look to solve this? Maybe this is not possible but can you see any alternative solution?

I understand how to define a model that as no management, by consider `managed=False` like i found on [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed), but how can i create an customized SQL view in my model class?

something like this:

```
Class myModel(models.Model):

   Object = models.raw("CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM table.A")
   class Meta:   
    db_table = 'myview\".\"mymodeltable'
    managed = False
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 0):

With `inspectdb` management command, you can obtain the models definition from existing tables. To do that, you need to configure your **settings.py** file to have access to the database you want to work with and then do:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

You will see that it also automatically sets the `managed=False`. From that point, you can start querying its objects with typical `objects.all(), objects.filter()` and this stuff

> Note: Don't forget to add the app with the imported models to the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable of your **settings.py** file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately maybe this is the final answer that can be found on [DjangoDocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#managed)

> This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means.